# Centralizar input verticalmente dentro de panel-heading

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Como posso centralizar este input de pesquisa para ficar na linha do texto?
Tentei aplicar margem mas em vez de subir, ele empurra a tabela para baixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código Atual:

```
         <!-- tabela servicos solicitados -->
            <div id="paineldeordens" class="panel panel-default pull-left" style="width:74%">
              <div class="panel-heading">Lista de serviços solicitados
                  <div class="form-group has-feedback pull-right" id="pesquisadiv">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-2 input-sm" id="inputbusca"/>
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que um `clearfix` resolve.

Comment: @Guilherme funcionou em partes, ficou assim http://prntscr.com/h5egvt

Comment: Seu input esta dentro de um `form-group class` e ele possui margins acho que é `margin-bottom: 5px;` tente tirar a margin dele.

Comment: Retirei, o resultado ta bom até, mas vou tentar centralizar o texto verticalmente

Comment: Dependendo o input pode afetar o texto do lado esquerdo, aí você pode trabalhar com `line-height` talvez teu input fique centralizado, mas o texto não, dando impressão que o input não está.